# Elastic IP changing IP and not associating with instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have created an Elastic IP. The IP address listed seems to be stable. It is associated with an instance. However, I get this weird behaviour:

- The public DNS listed for that IP contains a different address than the literal IP address.
- The public DNS does *not* resolve to the Elastic IP; it resolves to the IP implied by the DNS name.
- Stopping and starting the instance changes the IP address.

I've tried creating a new elastic IP address and a new instance and associating them, and I experience the same bug. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are looking at the AWS console, not the output of a program using the API directly.

The "public DNS" you see in the console is the public DNS of the instance, not of the elastic IP address. If the instance is associated with an ElasticIP, its public DNS should include the ElasticIP in it and resolve to the ElasticIP. Since it isn't, I suspect a bug in the AWS console. I've noticed a lot of lag in it showing the addresses when ElasticIP addresses are associated or disassociated. To confirm this, you might try completely clearing your browser history and cookies and reconnecting to the console, to see if the display is now right. Or you could use a browser's incognito or private browsing mode.

If you create the obvious public DNS to match your ElasticIP address, I'll bet it resolves correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the public Elastic IP address is stable (which, of course, is why they exist).

Are you referring to the fact the DNS name will resolve to a different IP address depending on whether you are resolving inside or outside AWS?

If so, this is a feature not a "bug".

If you look up a host name from outside AWS you get the *public* IP. If you look up the same name from, say, the command line of an EC2 instance you get the *private* IP (typically a 10.0.0.0 address).

This means that you can refer to an instance by a single name but internal traffic is automatically routed over the local network and not over the (billable) public interface.